# cursor to select data from each row is in infinite loop

Tags: loops, cursor

This site has helped me so much in the past.  Decided to try asking my own question:

I have to trim and concatenate strings that are stored in separate records.  The column in the one table only holds up to 255 characters.  Any overflow text is stored in a separate table and its column also only holds up to 255 characters.  So, that table may have have multiple records for the same text. Just bad software that we have to use.

When I refer to getting rid of the junk in the column in my comments, I mean the crap they throw in at the end of each string to indicate that there is more text in another record.

My problem is that the cursors seems to be in an infinite loop; the string that is returned continuously repeats the entire text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnDesc] (@id int)
RETURNS varchar(7000)
AS

begin                  
/*getting rid of junk in event_text (if there is any) and 
      setting @entireDesc to event_text*/                   
declare @entireDesc varchar(7000)
declare @cnt int
declare @data varchar(5000)
select @cnt = COUNT(*) from events e, oevent_text o where e.event_id = o.event_id and e.event_id = @id  

--data in oevent_text, need to strip
if @cnt > 0
select @entireDesc = left(t.event_text, len(t.event_text) - 4) from events e, event_text t where e.event_id = t.event_id and e.event_id = @id

--there is no data in oevent_text
else 
select @entireDesc = t.event_text from events e, event_text t where e.event_id = t.event_id and e.event_id = @id

/*getting rid of junk in oevent_text, concatenating it to @entireDesc, determine last record so that doesn't get stripped*/
declare @rows int
declare cur cursor local scroll for
select data from events e, oevent_text o where e.event_id = o.event_id and e.event_id = @id order by o.segm

open cur
fetch next from cur into @data 

--returns the number of rows in the cursor 
set @rows = @@CURSOR_ROWS

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 
    --if last record, don't strip characters
    if @rows = 1
        select @entireDesc = @entireDesc + o.data from events e, oevent_text o where e.event_id = o.event_id and e.event_id = @id
    --4 characters need to be stripped at the end
    else
    select @entireDesc = @entireDesc + left(o.data, len(o.data) - 4) from R25.dbo.events e, oevent_text o where e.event_id = o.event_id and e.event_id = @id

    set @rows = @rows - 1

    fetch next from cur into @data
end
close cur
deallocate cur

return @entireDesc

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding begin and end to the if statements

```
--if last record, don't strip characters
    if @rows = 1
       BEGIN
        select @entireDesc = @entireDesc + o.data from events e, oevent_text o where e.event_id = o.event_id and e.event_id = @id
    --4 characters need to be stripped at the end
       END
    else
       BEGIN
    select @entireDesc = @entireDesc + left(o.data, len(o.data) - 4) from R25.dbo.events e, oevent_text o where e.event_id = o.event_id and e.event_id = @id
       END
```